# Program crashes at findContours() in VS2012 and works in VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, visual-studio-2012

I have a code that works fine with VS2010 but crashes with VS2012.

I am using OpenCV 2.4.6 version.

My path variable for VS2010 is **`\vc10`** folder and for VS2012 it is **`\vc11`** folder.

As I said above with VS2010 everything works fine but when the same code is executed in VS2012 in both Debug/Release mode I get the following exception :

> Unhandled exception at 0x000007FEEB59733E (opencv_imgproc246d.dll) in
>   program.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location
>   0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.

The problem here is a `findContours()` function

[image]

After running .exe program from Release folder I get an error in console:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (curve.checkVector(2) >= 0 &&
>   (curve.depth() == CV_32F || curve.depth() == CV_32S)) in unknown
>   function, file ......\src\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\contours.cpp,
>   line 1886

Why is this so?

Comment: It happens because there's a bug in your code. Since you are using a debugger, I think the best thing would be for you to use that debugger to track down how you get those strange numbers in your data. Sorry but there's not really anything else to say.

Comment: So a bug in my code is a culprit here that my program works like a charm with VS2010 ?

Comment: It's common that bugged code can work correctly on one compiler and fail on another, or that bugged code can give the right answer *sometimes*. It's one of the joys of programming in C++. The 99.9% likely explanation is that you have a bug in your code, but there's not enough information here to even guess what that might be.

Comment: Check that your application loads correct OpenCV DLLs. Check PATH variable and make sure that path to vc11vc11 is used for VS2012.